# The method 'useEffect' isn't defined for the type

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and I want to implement the [`useEffect`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_hooks/latest/flutter_hooks/useEffect.html) hook.

Here is my widget:

```dart
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MarketRunnerChart extends StatefulWidget {
  const MarketRunnerChart({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MarketRunnerChart> createState() => _MarketRunnerChartState();
}

class _MarketRunnerChartState extends State<MarketRunnerChart> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    useEffect(() {
      log('okok');
    }, []);

    return Text("Some text");
  }
}
```

But I got the error `The method 'useEffect' isn't defined for the type '_MarketRunnerChartState'.`
[image]
When I remove the `useEffect` hook out of the `build` function and put it directly in the class I got error `'useEffect' must have a method body because '_MarketRunnerChartState' isn't abstract.`
[image]
I'm used to work with React, but right now with flutter I can't figure out how to implement that hook.

How am I supposed to do this ?

Comment: Import this library https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks and your widget must extend `HookWidget` instead of `StatefulWidget`.

Comment: Good tutorial about hooks:  https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-hooks-7754df814995

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try add

`import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';`

on top of your class file

Answer (score 2):

import flutter hooks

```
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

class MarketRunnerChart extends StatefulWidget {
    const MarketRunnerChart({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    State<MarketRunnerChart> createState() => _MarketRunnerChartState();
}

class _MarketRunnerChartState extends State<MarketRunnerChart> {
    useEffect(() {
        print('your log');
    }, []);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return Text("Some text");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the doc example, import `flutter_hooks`, extend the `HookWidget`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

class Example extends HookWidget {
  const Example({Key? key, })
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     //your variable/instance like to listen
    useEffect(() {
      log('okok');
    }, [...listenThisInstance...]);
    return Container();
  }
}
```

More about [useEffect](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_hooks/latest/flutter_hooks/useEffect.html)